# Is multiplying the matrix by its conjugate-transpose and divide by Frobenius norm something special for the matrix itself

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

Assuming a complex matrix $A$ with $n$ x $m$ dimension. What does mean multiplying $A$ with its conjugate transpose and divide by Frobenius norm? ($AA^H$ / $||A||_F$ ).

I'm asking that question because I noticed something about that. suppose that I have $y = hA$, where $h$ is a matrix of dimension $n$ x $m$ too. the results of $A^Hy / ||A||_F$  has always the same sign of $y$. for that I asked

Is that something special for any complex matrix $A$ ?

Comment: However the trace of this matrix is exactly the Frobenius norm of $A$...
Since
$$||A||_F^2=tr(AA^H)$$
You have
$$tr(\frac{AA^H}{||A||_F})=||A||_F$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider observing $N$ variables $M$ times each, you may stack your observation results into a $N\times M$ matrix $A$. If we can assume that the mean of each row of $A$ is zero, then $C = AA^H$ is the $N\times N$ covariance matrix, which tells you how well can every pair of variables be described by a linear relationship. Dividing the matrix by the Frobenius norm looks like an attempt at normalization. I'm not sure what that normalization achieves however

Comment: Does the result of that is always positive ?

Comment: No, covariance can be negative. The diagonal entries are always positive, the off-diagonal entries can be anything

Comment: I'm asking that question because I noticed something about that. suppose that I have $y = hA$, where $h$ is a matrix of dimension $m$ x $n$ too. the results of $A^Hy / ||A||_F$  has always the same sign of $y$. for that I asked